# Loading luasql-mysql in CMD

Tags: mysql, lua, luasql

I finally installed (I think) luasql-mysql in windows but I can't seem to run

```
local mysql = require("luasql-mysql").
```

Below are the relevant images:

[Image of Installed luasql-mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9neBu.png)
.

[Error in simple command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrNmX.png)

It seems like I only have mysql.dll after installation.

Comment: `require 'luasql.mysql'` ?

Comment: It is still module not found.  I did a search in windows and it seems like  there is no luasql.mysql LUA file. Did I miss something? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should there be luasql.lua that need to be installed?

Comment: there should be `luasql\mysql.dll` file.

Comment: Yes. I found the mysql.dll file. Do I need to put it in environment path? Thanks.

Comment: Call `luarocks path` and you should see what you need to add to environment. (there 2 variables LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH)

Comment: Copy your `luasql\mysql.dll` file to `c:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1\src\luasql\mysql.dll` and try `require 'luasql.mysql'`

Comment: Hello moteus thank you so much for your help. I added the variable but I got the following error: error loading module 'luasql.mysql' from file 'C:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1\src\systree/lib/lua/5.1luasql\mysql.dll: the specified module could not be found.

Comment: By the way, I change something in luasql-mysql-csv-1.rockspec, does this matter? - sources = { "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/luasql-master/src/luasql.c", "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/luasql-master/src/ls_mysql.c" }, –

Comment: `C:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1\src\systree/lib/lua/5.1luasql\my‌​sql.dll` forgot slash after `lua\5.1`. LUA_PATH value should contains `C:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1\src\systree\lib\lua\5.1\?.lua`

Comment: @moteus thanks. I followed it. At least I have a new error: "error loading module 'luasql.mysql' from file 'C:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1\src\systree/lib/lua/5.1/luasql\mysql.dll

Comment: I have given up on running anything other than standard lua on windows a long time ago xD

Comment: Sorru it should be LUA_CPATH and ending with `?.dll` not `?.lua`

Comment: I am still getting error after adding C:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1\src\systree\lib\lua\5.1\?.dll in LUA_CPATH in user and system variables. Maybe I should just use node.js instead of using luasql for interfacing database. Thanks moteus.

Comment: I hope you remove preview line from LUA_PATH?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Other operating system ok?